# Is it possible to convert regular text to a .story file?

Tags: nlp

The [DMQA Dataset](https://cs.nyu.edu/~kcho/DMQA/) contains news articles from CNN and Daily Mail in .story format. How can I convert a regular text data to .story format? 
Thank you.

A .story file looks like your regular text file, and can easily be accessible with code similar to python text opening. But this format is required for the preprocessing done in ( https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.10318.pdf ) .

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2AGE.png)

Comment: Is the .story format documented anywhere?

Comment: @OliverMason could you clarify what you mean by documented? I have json files with texts that I can extract, I was wondering if I could convert them

Comment: What do those json file look like? I don't want to download the whole lot just to have a look.

Comment: @OliverMason i edited the question with a link to an image